# Proof of $\sqrt{\pi/2}$ in birthday paradox?

Tags: reference-request, birthday-attack

I had found in the past a publication in a crypto conference (in 80s if i am not mistaken) which I believe was the first proof why for example a random function $f:X\rightarrow X$ with $\#X=2^n,$ is expected to have collision in $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}\times 2^n}$ iterations. I can't find it, anyone has the reference?

Comment: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00075445/document

Comment: boss, thanks. Is it that trivial? why the downvote

Comment: @AntonisParagas don't take the down-votes personally. Many people are too lazy to answer / comment to correct you. For me - what do you mean "expected to have collision"? Though - nice reading from SEJPM

Comment: Dropped an upvote... for whatever that's worth.

Comment: haha cheers, i was just wondering if it was out of line or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper you are looking for is:

*"Random Mapping Statistics"* by Flajolet and Odlyzko, first published in  Advances in Cryptology — EUROCRYPT ’89. EUROCRYPT 1989. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 434.

It is freely available via [SpringerLink](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-46885-4_34) and via [Archives-Ouvertes (PDF)](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00075445/document).

The relevant statistic you are looking for is probably the rho-length, which specifies the specifies the average length of a cycle to be $\sqrt{\pi n/2}$ where $n=2^k$ in your case.

The abstract reads as:

> Random mappings from a finite set into itself are either a heuristic
>   or an exact model for a variety of applications in random number
>   generation, computational number theory, cryptography, and the
>   analysis of algorithms at large. This paper introduces a general
>   framework in which the analysis of about twenty characteristic
>   parameters of random mappings is carried out: These parameters are
>   studied systematically through the use of generating functions and
>   singularity analysis. In particular, an open problem of Knuth is
>   solved, namely that of finding the expected diameter of a random
>   mapping. The same approach is applicable to a larger class of discrete
>   combinatorial models and possibilities of automated analysis using
>   symbolic manipulation systems (“computer algebra”) are also briefly
>   discussed.